# Build Error "Maximum number of errors has been exceeded" file vbc

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASP.NET Version 4 project. When I opened the project this morning and tried running it I got a build error " The maximum number of errors has been exceeded" with the item vbc in the file column. As far as I know the project would build that last time I worked on it. I excluded the files I was working on last from the project and I still get this error. Since the error message is ambiguous I can't even tell where to start. I found a reference to this message on another site which said you could increase the data base error limit in settings. I did this but of no help. This isn't a database issue anyway as far as I can tell. Visual studio sees the database. I can open through Server Explorer.

Any suggestions on how to start troubleshooting this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add the attribute "**targetFramework="4.0"** " in the compilation node of the web.config file

I had this issue and couldn't figure it out.  Zaf Khan's answer didn't help.  I got the project along with it's solution our code repository and apparently we hadn't looked at or change it for a while so I really didn't know where to start.  I copied the project (a web application) and pasted it into another directory and tried to open in with visual Studio.  Visual Studio gave me the pop-up requesting to upgrade the project to .Net 4.0 then it clicked.  I needed to add the attribute "targetFramework="4.0" " in the compilation node of the web.config file.  That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open your project and close all open documents in your VS 2010/2012

And then click on the COLUMN Header as shown in the image below.
Ensure the found errors numbers are ascending.

Then skip through each one till you find the issue.

Its probably something simple like a speech marks missing (like when you have an open quote somewhere).

[image]

Comment: Thanks Zaf. What I would see in the Error list was only the ambiguous statement "Maximum number of errors has been exceeded." I did find the source of the errors. I had copied a page and started to modify a week ago, them went back and revised some supporting classes. The site would run, but the errors were coming from the partially completed page. My dumb error. I exluded the page and the site build. Put the page back in and I get a list of 102 errors. For some reason they show now. I'll remove the question when the requisite time passes.

Comment: Its best NOT to remove the question. I suffered the same problem myself, and its how we learn. If another person has the same problem maybe they too can resolve it and possibly even, not lose sleep! As i did when my app went t*ts up with the same kind of problem.