# Visual Studio 2010 Error Message

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, c#-4.0

Yesterday night i was working on a project in visual studio 2010. everything seemed to work great. Today morning when i opened my project suddenly i got 102 errors and all of them are related to generic components which are in microsoft.visualbasic and windows.forms class. I have no clue of what happened. I have more than 80 classes, 45 forms and Huge amount of coding.

I googled and tried to remove n add all reference.. but still its same..

I tried to add and remove reference but nothing worked.. can anyone please point me to proper direction??

Comment: nope. still its same. :(

Comment: It may help more if you at least show some of the errors here...

Answer (score 4):

When visual studio gets wonky I always try:

The small guns: Rebuild All - sometimes help.

The big guns: Close visual studio. Delete all bin and obj directories. Helps most of the time, if not try again but delete the suo file as well.

You might also want to let someone else to look at the problem. It may be something simple you've overlooked. Also try to look at the errors relating to your application. Sometimes a single character typed by mistake in one of the files may cause a truck load of errors.

Last: use source control. That way you can always load from source control to a new directory a version you know for sure works and rule out (or not) problems with your computer.

Comment: Tried small gun - same. big guns - same. Most of Errors are generic like, it shows an error that msgbox is not declared, IIF is not declared, vbCF vbLf is not declared.. like those... i am not sure to what to do.. :(

Comment: Another thing, IsNothing is generic and now its throwing error for that also. I am dam sure that there is something with .Net. I tried to create new project, it works but this doesnt.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question to this here

[Build Error "Maximum number of errors has been exceeded" file vbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021702/build-error-maximum-number-of-errors-has-been-exceeded-file-vbc/16021892#comment22853480_16021892)

The main thing is... Relax! its nothing serious,
Usually this type of error occurs because you forgot to close some quotes or something simple like that, but as a side effect it throws all the following lines out of sync and then you get gazillions of errors showing.